Upper semicontinuity of sequence of Hausdorff measures
This is exercise 12.2 of Measure theory and integration of Michael Taylor.
Let $(d_j)$ be a sequence of metrics on a compact space $X$ such that there exists $c,C>0$ with
$$ cd_0(x,y) \leq d_j(x,y) \leq Cd_0(x,y) $$
for all $x,y\in X$.
Suppose also that $(d_j)$ converge uniformly to a metric $d$.
I want to show that, for any $S$ Borel subset, $\delta > 0$ and $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$ \mathcal{H}_{d_j,\lambda\delta}^r(S) \leq \mathcal{H}_{d, \delta}^r(S) + \varepsilon$$
with $j$ big enough and $\lambda = C/c$ and
$$ \mathcal{H}^r_{d,\delta}(S) = \inf\{ \sum (\operatorname{diam}_d U_i)^r \mid S \subset \cup U_i, \operatorname{diam} U_i \leq \delta \} $$
the approximate $\delta$-Hausdorff measure.
However when I try I always get a factor $(c/C)^r$ and I don't know how to get ride of it as it is not clear if we can rescale our cover.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{H}^r_{d,\delta}(S) + \varepsilon &\geq
\sum (\operatorname{diam}_d U_i)^r \\
&\geq \sum \left( \frac{c}{C} \operatorname{diam}_{d_j} U_i\right)^r
\end{aligned}
$$

I think you need to use the uniform convergence of the $d_j$ to show that not only is $d$ equivalent to $d_0$ with constants $c,C$ but also equivalent to $d_j$ with constants $c_j$ and $C_j$ that converge to $1$.

@quarague This is not always true, see for example remark 7.2.8 in A course in metric geometry of Burago, Ivanov

The idea is the following one : the $\lambda$ constant only appears in order to check that you covering for the computation of $\mathcal{H}_{d,\delta}^r(S)$ also fits to compute the $\mathcal{H}_{d_j,\lambda\delta}^r(S)$, but then it has to disappear from you sum when $j$ is large enough using $d_j \rightarrow d$ uniformy.
Concretely, let us first show that for all subset $Y$ of $X$ fixed, $\mathbb{diam}_{d_j}(Y) \rightarrow \mathbb{diam}_d(Y)$. Indeed, if $\varepsilon > 0$, then you can find points $(x,y) \in Y^2$ such that $d(x,y) \geqslant \mathbb{diam}_d(Y) - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. By convergence of $d_j$ toward $d$, for $j$ large enough, $d_j(x,y) \geqslant \mathbb{diam}_d(Y) - \varepsilon$ hence $\mathbb{diam}_d(Y) \leqslant \mathbb{diam}_{d_j}(Y) + \varepsilon$.
For the reverse inequality, consider for all $j$, a couple $(x_j,y_j) \in Y^2$ such that $d_j(x_j,y_j) \geqslant \mathbb{diam}_{d_j}(Y) - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. By uniform convergence of $d_j$ toward $d$, when $j$ is large enough, $d(x_j,y_j) \geqslant \mathbb{diam}_{d_j}(Y) - \varepsilon$, which implies that $\mathbb{diam}_{d_j}(Y) \leqslant \mathbb{diam}_d(Y) + \varepsilon$, proving the wanted convergence.
Having this result in mind, let $S \subset X$, $\delta > 0$ and $r \geqslant 0$ fixed, and let $\varepsilon > 0$. There is a finite covering of $S$ by open subsets $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ of $X$ such that for all $i$, $\mathbb{diam}_d(U_i) \leqslant \delta$ and,
$$
\sum_{i \in I} \mathbb{diam}_d(U_i)^r \leqslant \mathcal{H}_{d,\delta}^r(S) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
Using the uniform equivalence of the $d_j$ with the constants $c$ and $C$, we compute easily that for all $i$, $\mathbb{diam}_{d_j}(U_i) \leqslant \lambda\delta$ hence the covering $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ is admissible to deduce bounds on the $\mathcal{H}_{d_j,\lambda\delta}^r(S)$. Conretely, for all $j$,
$$
\sum_{i \in I} \mathbb{diam}_{d_j}(U_i)^r \geqslant \mathcal{H}_{d_j,\lambda\delta}^r(S).
$$
Now, we can use the result on the convergence of the diameters to deduce that,
$$
\sum_{i \in I} \mathbb{diam}_{d_j}(U_i)^r \rightarrow \sum_{i \in I} \mathbb{diam}_d(U_i)^r,
$$
when $j \rightarrow +\infty$. It works because $I$ is finite. Therefore, for $j$ large enough,
$$
\mathcal{H}_{d_j,\lambda\delta}^r(S) \leqslant \mathcal{H}_{d,\delta}^r(S) + \varepsilon.
$$
Notice that it can be reformulated as $\limsup_{j \rightarrow +\infty} \mathcal{H}_{d_j,\lambda\delta}^r(S) \leqslant \mathcal{H}_{d,\delta}^r(S)$.
